# Creating SSIS package for XML file for required data in Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Developers, I am working on SSIS and I want to create package to populate the XMLdata in the database from an XML source file and my source file sample data is here:

```
    <MeterReadings Purpose="OnRequestRead" CollectionTime="2013-08-09 
    19:57:11" Initiator="OnRequest" SourceIrn="30" 
    SourceName="coll_0591_stuart" Source="Remote" Irn="21">

    <Meter MediaType="900 MHz" ObservesDaylightSavings="true" 
    TimeZoneOffset="300" Timezone="(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" 
    TimeZoneIndex="11" Location="" SdpIdent="" AccountName="" 
    AccountIdent="" RemovalDate="" InstallDate="2013-05-01 20:28:09" 
    Description="" MeterType="REX" SerialNumber="03310266" IsActive="true" 
    MeterName="03310266" MeterIrn="21"/>

    <ConsumptionData>
    <ConsumptionSpec Multiplier="1" 
    MeasurementPeriod="EndOfIntervalSnapshot" TouBucket="Total" 
    Direction="Delivered" UOM="kWh"/>
    <Reading Value="73180" TimeStamp="2013-08-09 00:00:00"/>
    </ConsumptionData>

    <ConsumptionData>
    <LoadProfileSummary>
    <IntervalData>
    <IntervalData>
    <IntervalSpec Multiplier="0.1" Direction="Received" UOM="kWh" 
    TimestampEnd="2013-08-09 00:00:00" TimestampStart="2013-08-02 00:15:00" 
    Channel="2" Interval="15"/>
    <Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 00:15:00" RawReading="0"/>
    <Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 00:30:00" RawReading="0"/>
    <Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 00:45:00" RawReading="0"/>
```

In the database table I have columns  TimeStamp column and the Meterdirection column and I need the both values to populate in the columns of the table and there is one more table in available in the database with Meterdirection type with Delivered=1 and Received=2, So now how can I create the package in SSIS  can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge with SSIS so far? The way you are asking your question, it sounds like that you want someone to give you a step-to-step manual to do this. If not, I guess you have to ask the question which you exactly have more specifically.

Comment: Thank you for your response Developer, I do have knowledge on SSIS and also created a package to Extract the XML file used the XML source and for the Load OLEDB Destination and in transformation I used the Derived column to get required column but in the destination table, MeterDataId is not populating.Can you help me on this?

Comment: What is the error message on this then? You need to give more information. What datatype does this field have? Your information here is way to vague. It may a good idea for you to post some screenshots on this.